# Multiple 30A outlets on the same breaker

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I am upgrading my Garage/Shop electrical installation and adding a few 30Amp circuits. Is there any electrical code restrictions to have multiple 30A outlets on the same 30A breaker?

Comment: BTW: is this circuit 120V only, 240V only, or 120/240V?

Comment: The circuit is 240v only.

Comment: We've gone crazy looking for this in code, and have not had any luck.  We can't find anywhere in Code where it says you can't.    No one piece of plugged in equipment can exceed 80% of load, but then that's the rule *anyway* because of continuous-load rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, as long as you don't overload the circuit of course

This is stated most clearly in NEC 210.23(B):

> **210.23 Permissible Loads, Multiple-Outlet Branch Circuits.** In no case shall the load exceed the branch-circuit
>   ampere rating. A branch circuit supplying two or more outlets or receptacles shall supply only the loads specified
>   according to its size as specified in 210.23(A) through (D)
>   and as summarized in 210.24 and Table 210.24.

...

> **(B) 30-Ampere Branch Circuits.** A 30-ampere branch circuit shall be permitted to supply fixed lighting units with
>   heavy-duty lampholders in other than a dwelling unit(s) or
>   utilization equipment in any occupancy. A rating of any one
>   cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment shall not
>   exceed 80 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating.